# appending .txt files to dataframe populates NaN after 1st column read from loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Apologies for asking what seems like a common question. I have not found this iteration of the question on this forum.

I am reading some .txt files that contain just 1 column of values each, and I am create a larger dataframe to store them and process all. Here is how my code looks like generally:

```
dataPath=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), Project)
data=pd.DataFrame()
for filename in os.listdir(dataPath):
    if filename.endswith((".txt")):
        columnName=os.path.basename(filename)
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dataPath,filename), index_col=None,header=0,names=[columnName],dtype=float)
        data=data.append(df)
```

So you can see that I'm reading in some files, naming the new columns the filename, and appending new frames for each loop. When I do this, the output is:

```
  Alphas.txt  Betas.txt  ...  Thetas.txt  TimeSteps.txt
0       13.08        NaN  ...         NaN            NaN
1      -11.68        NaN  ...         NaN            NaN
2      -26.42        NaN  ...         NaN            NaN
3       57.71        NaN  ...         NaN            NaN
4      -53.81        NaN  ...         NaN            NaN

[5 rows x 6 columns]
```

But those files are populated and should not be NaN. When I print the df in the loop, they all show up like a dataframe, for example, printing Thetas gives me

```
         Thetas.txt
    0         -5.90
    1         47.74
    2         -7.67
    3         77.31
    4         18.51
    ..          ...
    112       10.80
    113        8.03
    114      -56.47
    115       -8.46
    116      -35.35
[117 rows x 1 columns]
```

So I would like that final `data` dataframe to be fully populated with the correct values and not NaN. I was suspicious that I was not passing the right datatype, so I tried to specify that as I read the .txt files. I'm not sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Should I be using concat here instead, or merge?

Comment: do each of the files have the same number of rows?

Comment: @DavidErickson yes they do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try:

```
dataPath=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), Project)
data=pd.DataFrame()
for filename in os.listdir(dataPath):
    if filename.endswith((".txt")):
        columnName=os.path.basename(filename)
        df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(dataPath,filename), index_col=None,header=0,names=[columnName],dtype=float)
        data[columnName] = df[columnName]
```

Then now printing `data` would give the expected result.

Comment: This fix was frustratingly simple. Thank you. I guess I tried to overcomplicate this.